# Update several objects with formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, formsets

I'm 1st year on CS so forgive my noobness if i am totally unclear.

I have several objects from my "Products" Model. Now I would like to update the same field on all of the objects, the 'quantity' field with different values. But instead of clicking in and out of each product as with updateview, i would like to list all products and set the value for each and change them at the simultaneously. As far as i can see "FormSet" should do the trick?

My category model looks like this (to assign for a product)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

My Product model looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My update view for updating single product looks like this:

```
class UpdateProductView(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = "product_form.html"
    success_url = '/products'

class CreateCategoryView(FormView):
    template_name = "category_form.html"
    form_class = CategoryForm
```

I read the documentation on formset, but i gotta admit i didn't feel much smarter about how to actually use it afterwards.. can anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find `quantity` field on your `Product` model, but as I can see, you want to use ModelFormSet.

```
# Generate your formset class with `modelformset_factory`
ProductFormSetClass = modelformset_factory(Product, fields=('quantity',))
# Now you can create your formset, bind data, etc
formset = ProductFormSetClass(request.POST)
formset.save()
```

More details by link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Also, don't forget to inspect all [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory) arguments.

Comment: Ahh yes ofcourse, what i meant was 'stock' and not quantity.
Do i define this as a seperate function or do i make a new view for this? I find it a bit confusing :D

Comment: It works like forms in Django, you can bind data, validate each form inside formset with .is_valid() method, etc, but first you should create class with factory instead of declare it. If you really want to understand how it works, try to implement it by yourself with simple view. An example in docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates Then you can try to use generic views from `django-extra-views` app